# 'SharedPreferencesUtils()' has private access in 'com.google.android.gms.common.util.SharedPreferencesUtils

Tags: android

why i am getting this error. I am trying to create session management for signup and login activity.

I got error in this line " pref = new SharedPreferencesUtils(context); "

help me to correct it.

here is my code -

```html
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import com.google.android.gms.common.util.SharedPreferencesUtils;

public class SessionManagement {

    SharedPreferencesUtils pref;
    Context context;

    public SessionManagement(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        pref = new SharedPreferencesUtils(context);

    }

    public void createLoginSession(String s, String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4, boolean b) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to save user login credentials using sharedpreferences ?

Comment: yes yes and also trying to save login session. so user do not have to login again

Comment: Okey you just need to simply use sharedpreferences

Comment: @takieddine  okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sample of code from my project , follow these step  :

- Create function that will store the data

```
 // Call this function where you want to save your data

 private void storeCredentials(String email , String password) {
        SharedPreferences credentialsPrefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = credentialsPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString("email",email);
        editor.putString("password",password);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

- Then Call your preferences where you have your edittexts to set data

```
  SharedPreferences credentialsPrefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String email  = credentialsPrefs.getString("email","default-value");
        String password = credentialsPrefs.getString("password","default-       value");
```

Comment: thanks i will try it but i don't  know how to use this. can you help me personally. we can connect on social media.